# CSS3 Media Query Smoothness

Tags: css, width, media

I have a little problem here;
Here's my code :

```
.big-header {
     font-size: 120px;
     font-weight: bolder;
     color: #fff;
     text-align: left;
     padding-left: 139px;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
     .big-header {
         font-size: 40px;
     }  
}
```

Everything works the way I want it to, but there's a real smoothness problem, I mean is there a way for the font-size to resize smoothly as the width is down? When I resize my window it goes directly from 120px to 40px. Is there a way font-size could slowly decrease? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think this is an issue because real users (public) don't usually resize their browser to phone size. You can always add more break points to reduce the size gradually but I don't think it's needed

Comment: ^ true but screw that, much like my cat 'if it fits, i sits' only in this context it would be 'if i can do it, i do it'... besides, it's easy to do :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a css transition to both the type and when the type shrinks: `transition: all 2s;`

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/chfhd5L0/3/

```css
.big-header {
     font-size: 120px;
     font-weight: bolder;
     text-align: left;
     padding-left: 139px;
    transition: all 2s;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
     .big-header {
         font-size: 40px;
    transition: all 2s;
     }  
}
```

```html
<p class="big-header">Hello</p>
```

Comment: Assuming supported browser can handle css transitions. Also on FF mac, the animation is only 1 way. But if you use transition all for both then it works http://jsfiddle.net/chfhd5L0/1/ Although I am not sure if this kind of change is suitable for a website, you are going to need to test this implementation completely with the rest of the site/page

Comment: Oops, the link I sent was the wrong one. I kept the transition as width instead of all, bahaha... and wrong again, I kept the text as white. Should be fine now. As for browser compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Comment: Thanks Huangism and lots of thanks to chdltest!!! transition: all 2s; is perfectly what I was looking for :) And I agree, no one should see the transition, but I needed it to showcase how it would work so it's perfect guys! THANKS again :)